# Presto nodes will only work as coordinators, not as workers

Tags: presto

We are using Presto 0.150 on 3 nodes, one coordinator and two workers. The setup worked fine before, when we were still using 0.147. Now however, while the coordinator works fine, the workers will reply to anything with a 404 error page, even when using the presto cli on the same node to query the system catalog.

When we ask the coordinator about the state of the cluster, it reports all three nodes as active. But doing anything with the coordinators always just gives 404 error pages.

Here is what we tried:

- When we change the workers to become coordinators, effectively hacking the cluster into three separate nodes, they work fine.
- When we give the workers a wrong coordinator url, they throw errors on startup.
- The coordinator (and its port 8080) is reachable from the workers (tested with curl).
- There are no errors or anything visibly out of the ordinary in the log files.

[You can see a worker server.log here](http://pastebin.com/raw/PdNJXi2X). Careful, it's verbose, we enabled DEBUG logging trying to find out what went wrong.

Now we are completely out of ideas. I hope you can help us.

Comment: Only the coordinator is expected to respond to clients like the CLI. Is that not working? In 0.149, we fixed a long-standing issue that made workers expose all the same APIs as the coordinator.

Comment: @MartinTraverso Okay, so if I understand correctly, we have been using presto wrong, and all requests, like the CLI or JDBC are supposed to go through the coordinator. And the fact that it worked before was due to a bug that got fixed in 0.149. Is that it?

Comment: @MartinTraverso Making all requests through the coordinator does seem to have solved the problem. However, in the HTTP access logs of the workers, we see lots of 404 errors of the coordinator doing HEAD requests for /. I do not think this is supposed to happen..?